# A convergent series for the Trigamma function $\psi_1(n) =\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac1{k^2} $

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, digamma-function, polygamma

I just came up with
the following
convergent series
for the Trigamma function
defined by

$\psi_1(n)
=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac1{k^2}
$.

\begin{align*}
\psi_1(n)
&=\lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^m \frac{(j-1)!}{j\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}(n+i)}\\
&=\frac1{n}+\frac{1}{2n(n+1)}+\frac{2}{3n(n+1)(n+2)}+\ldots\\
\end{align*}

This contrasts with
the usual asymptotic series
for $\psi_1(n)$
which is asymptotic,
does not converge,
and involves the
Bernoulli numbers.

I'm sure this isn't new,
but I could not find it here.

So,
my questions are,
as is often the case,

(1) Is this new?

(2) Is there a reasonably simple proof?
(Mine is moderately messy.)

I'll post my proof
in a few days
if anyone is interested.

Thanks

Comment: I don't remember seeing this in English, but they're called by the calque of "factorial series" in German, and the ones for the polygamma functions are super old

Comment: Do you know of a reference?

Comment: Nielson, Niels. 1906. Handbuch der theorie der gammafunktion. Leipzig : Teubner. http://archive.org/details/handbuchgamma00nielrich (p 83)
Also Schlömilch, 1859. Uber facultätenreihen. Zeitschrift für Mathematik und Physik (4), p 396. (p 408).
But the original idea is probably in Stiriling (1730)

Comment: Thank you. I'll look them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}(n+i)=\Gamma(n+j)/\Gamma(n)$, so that, as claimed,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{(j-1)!}{j\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}(n+i)}
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1j\mathrm{B}(n,j)\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac1j\int_0^1 t^{n-1}(1-t)^{j-1}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1 t^{n-1}\frac{-\log t}{1-t}\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1 t^{n-1}(-\log t)\sum_{j=0}^\infty t^j\,dt\\
&=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\int_0^1 t^{k-1}(-\log t)\,dt=\sum_{k=n}^\infty\frac1{k^2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: That's a really nice proof. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a proof, not an answer but it is too long for comments.*

Let
$$a_j=\frac{(j-1)!}{j\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}(n+i)}=\frac{(j-1)!}{j n (n+1)_{j-1}}\qquad \text{and} \qquad S_m=\sum_{j=1}^m a_j$$

$$\frac{(m+1) \Gamma (n+1) \Gamma (m+n+1)}{\Gamma (n) }S_m=$$
$$(m+1) n \psi ^{(1)}(n) \Gamma (m+n+1)-$$ $$\Gamma (m+1) \Gamma (n+1) \,
   _3F_2(1,m+1,m+1;m+2,m+n+1;1)$$

Simplifying
$$S_m=\psi ^{(1)}(n)-\frac{\Gamma (m+1) \Gamma (n)}{(m+1)
   \Gamma (m+n+1)} \, _3F_2(1,m+1,m+1;m+2,m+n+1;1)$$

What seems interesting is to make a contour plot of the second term; it shows how small it is.

We can also notice that for large values of $m$ $(m\gg n)$, the coefficient
$$\frac{\Gamma (m+1) \Gamma (n)}{(m+1) \Gamma (m+n+1)}\sim \frac{ \Gamma (n) }{m^{n+1}}$$

Unfortunately, I have not been to find the asymptotics of the hypergeometric function.

Comment: If you take my series for $\psi_1$, regarding convergence the ratio test is inconclusive ($a_n/a_{n+1} = (1+1/j)(1+n/j)$ but Raabe's test gives $n+1+n/j$ so indicates convergence and the root test gives $2/e$ which also gives convergence.

Comment: @martycohen. Being very intested by the post, I must confess that I was hoping to find the asymptotics of the hypergeometric function in order to find $m$ such that the difference be smaller than $\epsilon$ (one of my hobbies). Cheers :-)